# Gram-Schmidt Orthonormalization

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, kerr-metric

In the paper from [Kulkarni et al., 2011](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.0010.pdf) (Appendix B1), a method is given for transforming from Boyer-Lindquist (BL) coordinates to a comoving frame.

This involves using [Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to determine the components of the transformation matrix $\Lambda$, that transforms the BL coordinates $e_{\nu}$ to the comoving frame coordinates $e_{\hat{\nu}}$. i.e.

$$ e_{\hat{\nu}} = \Lambda e_{\nu} $$

**Can anyone give an explicit example as to how this is done?**

I understand the Gram-Schmidt process as described in the linked Wikipedia article, but cannot see how to use this process to determine the *components of the transformation matrix*.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be a linear algebra question rather than a physics question - you seem to be asking how to obtain the transformation matrix between two given bases of a vector space. What's the physics content here?

Comment: Sorry maybe I should have been more explicit; the physics content comes from the context transforming between reference frames within a (e.g.) Kerr spacetime. If not appropriate I can move the question.